# Functional way to write these methods in F#

Tags: f#, idioms

In order to calculate the area of square and circle, I defined the following type:

```
type Square = {width: float; length: float;} with
    member this.area = this.width * this.length
    member this.perimeter = (this.width + this.length) * 2.

type Circle = {r:float} with 
    member this.area = System.Math.PI * this.r * this.r
    member this.perimeter = 2. * System.Math.PI * this.r

let s1 = {width = 3.; length = 4.}
let c1 = {r = 8.3}

printfn "%A" s1
printfn "The area of s1 is: %A" s1.area
printfn "The perimeter of s1 is: %A" s1.perimeter


printfn "%A" c1
printfn "The area of c1 is: %A" c1.area
printfn "The perimeter of c1 is: %A" c1.perimeter
```

When I read this article:
http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-extensions/

It states:

- Methods don't play well with type inference
- Methods don't play well with higher order functions

> So, a plea for those of you new to functionally programming. Don't use
>   methods at all if you can, especially when you are learning. They are
>   a crutch that will stop you getting the full benefit from functional
>   programming.

Then what's the functional way to solve this problem? or what's the idomatic F# way?

---

**Edit**:

After reading the  "The F# Component Design Guidelines" (curtsy to @V.B.), and @JacquesB's comment, I consider that implement the member method within the type is the most simple, intrinsic way:

```
type Square2 (width: float, length: float) =
    member this.area = width * length
    member this.perimeter = (width + length) * 2.
```

(This is almost identical with my original `Square` type -- this `Square2` only saves seveal `this.` prefix as in `this.width`, `this.length`.)

Again, the [The F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/) is quite useful.

Comment: More functional is not necessarily more idiomatic F#! F# is an oo/functional language, and appropriate use of methods are fine. The quote is really about *learning* functional programming when you already know oo, and in that case trying to be as functional as possible is a good learning exercise.

Comment: Regarding the two current answers, and the plea against "methods", use a discriminated union when you know all your cases up-front.  This is more functional and really maps your domain better--these N options are my only cases--and you'll learn more F# by it.  Use an interface (and methods) when you want to be able to define new implementations ad-hoc through your program.

Answer (score 8):

A more functional way to do this would be to create a `Shape` discriminated union, where `Square` and `Circle` would be its cases. Then create functions `area` and `perimeter`, taking `Shape` and using pattern matching:

```
type Shape =
    | Square of Width: float * Length: float
    | Circle of R: float

let area = function
    | Square (width, length) -> width * length
    | Circle r -> System.Math.PI * r * r

let perimeter = function
    | Square (width, length) -> (width + length) * 2.
    | Circle r -> 2. * System.Math.PI * r

let s1 = Square(Width = 3., Length = 4.)
let c1 = Circle(R = 8.3)

printfn "%A" s1
printfn "The area of s1 is: %A" (area s1)
printfn "The perimeter of s1 is: %A" (perimeter s1)


printfn "%A" c1
printfn "The area of c1 is: %A" (area c1)
printfn "The perimeter of c1 is: %A" (perimeter c1)
```

Comment: Why is this more functional? Please elaborate. Both approaches lack side-effects.

Comment: @rightfold One can only assume the question's intent, given that its implementation lacks side effects as well, is "how would one write this using features more commonly found in functional languages than OO languages", which seems to be one accepted definition of "functional" these days.  (Just as not-literally is one accepted definition of literally.  Don't shoot the messenger.)

Comment: @rightfold That's already explained in the question. For example `let f x = x.area` won't compile, while `let f x = area x` will.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more functional way that @svick describes well, but consider also **"[The F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/)"**

- Do use properties and methods for operations intrinsic to types.

> This is called out specifically because some people from a functional
>   programming background avoid the use of object oriented programming
>   together, preferring a module containing a set of functions defining
>   the intrinsic functions related to a type (e.g. length foo rather than
>   foo.Length). But see also the next bullet. In general, in F#, the use
>   of object-oriented programming is preferred as a software engineering
>   device. This strategy also provides some tooling benefits such as
>   Visual Studio’s “Intellisense” feature to discover the methods on a
>   type by “dotting into” an object.

- Consider using interface types to represent related groups of operations that may be implemented in multiple ways.

> In F# there are a number of ways to represent a dictionary of
>   operations, such as using tuples of functions or records of functions.
>   In general, we recommend you use interface types for this purpose.

So, according to these guidelines, an interface `IShape` with `Area` and `Perimeter` members is a recommended way for an F# component, despite there is a "more functional" way in general.

Comment: I don't think these two bullets imply needing an interface.  Both can be accomplished by type extensions in a more functional way.  Really the latter bullet is more about not making records of functions, which can be hard to understand.

Comment: @DaxFohl when comparing with svick's answer, IShape is what I understand as a "related group of operations that may be implemented in multiple ways" - Area and Perimeter. Pattern matching with a separate function for each case is not so far away from a record of functions.

Comment: Also note that those are *component* design guidelines, i.e. it describes how should the public surface of libraries look like, it doesn't affect the implementation.

Comment: Well, it's "consider", but there's also "Consider using F# extension members in F#-to-F# code and libraries".  I personally like that way better, since when you hit F12 to go-to-source, it'll take you to the actual implementation rather than just the interface declaration.  Interfaces are nice though when you want to be able to define new implementations later on in the code; discriminated unions force you to define them all up-front.  So, ultimately the choice depends on which option fits one's domain model better.

Comment: @svick I made it clear that this "consider" thing is for components and referred to your answer as the correct one for "functional way". In my experience, though, I like when an implementation for a square is within the square type and not in some module. Given that there is no mutable state and these are properties rather than methods, such a class with members is as "functional" as a module.

Comment: Thank you very much for the `The F# Component Design Guidelines` link. It is invalable! I read it from the beginning to the end, and it changed my mind on OOP vs FP.